# Titanium: Auto-select first row of dynamically created rows

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I have a two tab layout. When the first tab button is clicked the rows are filled using data retrieved remotely. This is the same for the second tab but the layout of the data is different.

My problem is when you switch between tabs I need to fire a click event on the first row of each tab.

I am building this app for android only.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

EDIT: This is dummy code of the top of head, hope it makes a bit more sense.

```
leftTableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  data: populateTableView(0),
  allowsSelection:true
}); 

function populateTableView(byType)
{
for(length of array loop){
    var tableViewRow=Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        my_obj:myObj[i]
    });

    tabledata=[]

    tableViewRow.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.row.setBackgroundImage('/images/selected-row-background.png');
    }

    if byType 0

        loop array display row for each object element
        tableData.push(tableViewRow);   
        return tabledata


    if byType 1

        loop array display row for each object element, display differently
        tableData.push(tableViewRow);   
        return tabledata
}
}

tab 1 click event listener

populateTableView(0);
leftTableView.data[0].rows[0].fireEvent('click');//this fires but says e.row.setBackgroundImage is undefined

tab 2 click event listener

populateTableView(1)
leftTableView.data[0].rows[0].fireEvent('click');//this fires but says e.row.setBackgroundImage is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the blur event on the tabGroup and take action as each one of the tabs become the active tab

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-event-blur

```
tabGroup.addEventListener('blur', function(_event) {
    var activeTab = _event.tab;

    // now that you have the activeTab, get the window, then the 
    // table and call a method to simulate a click on the first
    // row
});
```

passing data when firing event

```
var row = leftTableView.data[0].rows[0];
row.fireEvent('click', { row : row } )
```

Comment: Hey Aaron,

I should of mentioned this, my tabs do not open/close windows, they change the rows underneath the tabs. The data is displayed differently depending on which tab was clicked. I have a 'click' listener on each tab, when they are selected the table view is populated e.g. leftTableView.setData(function1) and leftTableView.setData(function2). Once this action is complete I need away to select the first row from the rows dynamically added. After the setData call on the tab click event listener I added. leftTableView.selectRow(0), this doesn't cause any errors but no row selected.

Comment: you need to pass some data when you fire the event. See edits above

Comment: Thanks so far... Now selects row, some labels have text set using the my_obj:myObj[i], this is now saying that this is undefined. If you can't/don't have the time to add a fix for this I will try figure out myself and mark as answer anyway. You are a life saver!

Comment: Figured it out, thank you. I never thought about passing additional data when firing event. This will help with other problems I have been having in other apps.